# How to Create a Pyramid Layout Using Foundation Grid

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I need to build a pyramid of content blocks using the Foundation grid.

The problem is that for rows that are not divisible by 12, I cannot stack the next row in the pyramid so that it is centered under the row above it.

It is like I need a half column offset or something equivalent.

I thought about using .centered on a nested row, but that seems to have the same problem of dividing half columns.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='small-1 small-centered columns'>1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class='small-5 columns'></div>
    <div class='small-1 columns'>1</div>
    <div class='small-1 columns'>2</div>
    <div class='small-5 columns'></div>
</div>
<!--- This row with 3 content blocks is not centered below the previous row --->
<div class="row">
    <div class='small-4 columns'></div>
    <div class='small-1 columns'>1</div>
    <div class='small-1 columns'>2</div>
    <div class='small-1 columns'>3</div>
    <div class='small-3 columns'></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/1cq1gqtq/

Comment: If it were me I wouldn't use the grid, but rather the block-grid. Of course if it  were me, I probably wouldn't be trying to built a pyramid with the Foundation grid anyway. You could make your own custom rows for columns that are divisible.

Comment: I was able to use block-grid, and it worked just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/4n481Lsf/ Post an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use block grid instead. The block grid utility will fill up whatever available space is created by the row above.

See the Foundation docs for examples of how to use it: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html

I use this a lot when I need no padding on the left/right sides of the outer columns.